# Prove Set is a Dedekind Cut

Tags: analysis, dedekind-domain

Consider: Let $y \in \mathbb{R}. Q_y = \{q \in \mathbb{Q} \mid q < y\}$. I would like to prove that $Q_y$ is a Dedekind cut, following the definitions below.

1. $d \neq \mathbb{Q}$ and $d \neq \emptyset$
2. $a \in d, b \in \mathbb{Q}, b < a \implies b \in d$ (downward closure)
3. $\forall a \in d, \exists b \in d$ such that $b>a$ (No greatest element)

I'm having trouble showing 2. Parts 1 and 3 seem straight forward since $Q_y \neq \mathbb{Q}$ and $Q_y \neq \emptyset$ where $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Part 3 also follows from $\sup(Q_y) = y$. I'm not convinced though that $Q_y$ has downward closure. The more I try to formulate a proof the less I think it's true, but I know that $Q_y$ is certainly a Dedekind cut.

Could someone please help with the proof of property 2 for this question?

Comment: There is a mistake somewhere, because if we take $Q_{5}$, we have that $4\in Q_{5}$ and $4> \pi$ but $\pi$ is not in $Q_{5}$

Comment: I think what you're missing in part 2 of the definition is the condition $b\in \mathbb Q$ on the left side of the implication: $a \in d, b < a, b\in \mathbb Q \implies b \in d.$

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly. I'm still not entirely sure how to prove property 2 for $Q_y$

Comment: If $a < y$ and $b < a$, can you conclude $b < y$?  (This is the only step in proving the corrected property 2, and is a basic, named, property of $<$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s pretty easy, you want to show that if $x\in Q_{y}$ and $z<x$ then $z\in Q_{y}$ but this is true because: if $x\in Q_{y}$ then $x<y$, so if $z<x$ then we must have $z<y$ and so $z\in Q_{y}$.Hence 2 is true.

Comment: So then, it's ok that $z$, isn't a fixed point, correct? This could hold for an arbitrarily small value of $z$; even close to -$\infty$

Comment: Yes, I assumed nothing about $z$ other then $z<x$.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much!

Comment: @ENV You’re welcome, if this answers your question please accept it to remove it from the unanswered queue .